# Undefined reference to klee when building s2e

Tags: cmake, makefile, llvm, reverse-engineering, klee

I'm trying to start a new prject and build s2e in a new directory. But at arounf the 100% mark, it gives me an undefined reference error. The relevant part (imo) is this:

```
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable ../ExprTest
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::setModule(llvm::Module*, klee::Interpreter::ModuleOptions const&, bool)':
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/include/klee/Internal/Module/KModule.h:189: undefined reference to `klee::KModule::KModule(llvm::Module*)'
```

My directory structure is such:

```
|-s2e-env
|-s2e_projects
|-venv
```

I followed the steps from here: http://s2e.systems/docs/s2e-env.html I followed all the steps upto `s2e build` which is where this problem occurs.

For reference, the (truncated) output which I got from doing `s2e build &> log`:

```
[ 88%] Built target kleeModule
make[3]: Entering directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Entering directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Entering directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Leaving directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Leaving directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Leaving directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Entering directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Entering directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
make[3]: Entering directory '~/s2e_projects/build/klee-release'
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable ../ADTTest
[ 91%] Linking CXX executable ../UtilsTest
[ 92%] Linking CXX executable ../ExprTest
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::setModule(llvm::Module*, klee::Interpreter::ModuleOptions const&, bool)':
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/include/klee/Internal/Module/KModule.h:189: undefined reference to `klee::KModule::KModule(llvm::Module*)'
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::setModule(llvm::Module*, klee::Interpreter::ModuleOptions const&, bool)':
~/s2e_projects/build/llvm-10.0.0.src/include/llvm/IR/DataLayout.h:393: undefined reference to `llvm::DataLayout::getPointerSize(unsigned int) const'
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::setModule(llvm::Module*, klee::Interpreter::ModuleOptions const&, bool)':
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:107: undefined reference to `klee::KModule::linkLibraries(klee::Interpreter::ModuleOptions const&)'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:108: undefined reference to `klee::KModule::buildShadowStructures()'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:110: undefined reference to `klee::KModule::prepare(klee::Interpreter::ModuleOptions const&, klee::InterpreterHandler*)'
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::initializeGlobalObject(klee::ExecutionState&, boost::intrusive_ptr<klee::ObjectState> const&, llvm::Constant const*, unsigned int)':
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:150: undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantDataSequential::getNumElements() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:151: undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantDataSequential::getElementAsConstant(unsigned int) const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:153: undefined reference to `llvm::DataLayout::getStructLayout(llvm::StructType*) const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:158: undefined reference to `klee::KModule::evalConstant(std::unordered_map<llvm::GlobalValue const*, klee::ref<klee::ConstantExpr>, std::hash<llvm::GlobalValue const*>, std::equal_to<llvm::GlobalValue const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<llvm::GlobalValue const* const, klee::ref<klee::ConstantExpr> > > > const&, llvm::Constant const*, klee::KInstruction const*)'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:163: undefined reference to `klee::ConstantExpr::ZExt(unsigned int)'
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::initializeGlobals(klee::ExecutionState&)':
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:200: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:241: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:247: undefined reference to `llvm::GlobalValue::isDeclaration() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:258: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:260: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:262: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:268: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:281: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:306: undefined reference to `klee::KModule::evalConstant(std::unordered_map<llvm::GlobalValue const*, klee::ref<klee::ConstantExpr>, std::hash<llvm::GlobalValue const*>, std::equal_to<llvm::GlobalValue const*>, std::allocator<std::pair<llvm::GlobalValue const* const, klee::ref<klee::ConstantExpr> > > > const&, llvm::Constant const*, klee::KInstruction const*)'
~/s2e_projects/source/s2e/klee/lib/Core/Executor.cpp:311: undefined reference to `llvm::Value::getName() const'
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::initializeGlobals(klee::ExecutionState&)':
~/s2e_projects/build/llvm-10.0.0.src/include/llvm/IR/GlobalVariable.h:92: undefined reference to `llvm::GlobalValue::isDeclaration() const'
../../lib/libkleeCore.a(Executor.cpp.o): In function `klee::Executor::initializeGlobals(klee::ExecutionState&)':

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same error and solved it with:

```
sudo apt install gcc-9 g++-9
```

Also check to make sure clang selects the installed gcc-9 toolchain:

```
$ PATH_TO_S2E/install/bin/clang++ -v
...
Selected GCC installation: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9
...
```

As for why a compatible gcc toolchain is needed, even though clang is used to compile S2E:
[Why clang selects a gcc installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24349124/why-clang-selects-a-gcc-installation)